# Merging of 2 Tables but different value of fields

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL to create a report to merge 2 tables. The problem is that I need 2 different headers and 1 column needs to have values from 2 different fields from the 2 tables.

Sample

```
Material             |         Plant
-------------------------------------------------
Component            |        Quantity


XXX - Material       |        ABC--Plant
--------------------------------------------------
YYYY-Component       |       3000- Quantity
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I think you should use Join, I guess....Can you show us the data of the two tables, and how you should to see your final table

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(

(select *,rn=row_number()over(order by column1) from table1)x,
(select *,rn1=row_number()over(order by column2) from table2)y
)
where x.rn=y.rn1
```

Firstly you need to give a extra column say rownumber,then repeat same for table2
then you can join using the row_numbers